# Can't connect to the internet after purging resolvconf

Tags: package-management, internet, resolvconf

I was trying to fix my internet because it wasn't working randomly, so I used the command

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf
```

Anyways, I got a lot of error messages after that and now my internet won't work even after restart!

I feel like it had to do with my repositories not connecting properly, but now I don't even have the internet to get repositories.

What should I do?

Comment: Easiest thing would be to reinstall.

Comment: I'd probably try creating a temporary resolver config e.g. `echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf` and **then** try reinstalling the resolvconf package (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf`)

Comment: @steeldriver downloading the package and installing it should work right. I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Download the resolvconf's DEB file using any other device and install it.

For Ubuntu 16.04,
http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/resolvconf/resolvconf_1.78ubuntu2_all.deb

For any other versions,

1. Go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=resolvconf
2. Select your version of Ubuntu
3. Click on **all** in the Download section
4. Click on any pool from the given list. e.g. `de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`.
5. Download the package and install it by `dpkg -i <package>.deb` e.g. `dpkg -i resolvconf_1.79ubuntu10_all.deb`.
6. Reboot the system `sudo reboot now`

Your internet should be back now.